# Combine dynamic list of object types into one large object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a dynamically generated type that produces an array where each element can be any of a set of types like so:

```
type Elements = (TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | ...)[] // this is dynamically generated
```

I have a way to extract each type in the array to a general "or" type without issues

```js
type IndividualElements = ArrayTypes<Elements>
// the above is results in dynamically generating this type:
type IndividualElements = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | ...
```

This works, but now I'd like to set up an object that contains every key/value from all types in the array. Basically creating a large object combining all properties, kind of like this except dynamically:

```js
type CombinedElement = TypeA & TypeB & TypeC & ...
```

I could write this out manually, but since each type is generated from a JSON schema automatically I'd rather have a type mechanism to do it dynamically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually quite fun and took me a while: based on another answer, you can do some pretty crazy shit with Conditional and Derived Types, basically take this type to convert Union to Intersection:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
```

So lets test the whole thing:

```
type test = UnionToIntersection<{} | { test: string } | { foo: number }>;
//produces to { test: string } & { foo: number }
```

EDIT:
You can even take this whole thing a step further by generating the union type from your array "on-the-fly":

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type list = {} | { test: string } | { foo: number };
type test = UnionToIntersection<list[number]>; //list[number] produces the union type
//also produces { test: string } & { foo: number }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This works as long as there are no conflicting property types. Is there a way for it to ignore conflicts in some manner? E.g.: `UnionToIntersection<{} | { test: string } | { test: number }>`

Comment: No, this is not possible as it's also not possible in normal union types, since TS can't decide which type to use then. Maybe in the future there will be the option to combine `{ test: string } & { test: number}` to `{ test: number | string }`, but as of now it is not possible

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. I'll see if I can reorganize my types so that your awesome `UnionToIntersection` can work.